# Contact Lookup with partial number

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a Contact Lookup by partial number, have tried several methods, including the one described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2ysulf/contact_lookup_by_partial_phone_number/ but still have numbers in my list that don't show up in these methods.

These numbers have separators in them like this: "00 1 963-899-6889" and in the ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI table have the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER column as NULL.

However if i try using the full match method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html with the search query = "9638996889"(the number without separators) it finds it.

This is the resulting row of a full match query:

```
number: 00 1 963-899-6889
contact_id: 136
photo_uri: null
phonebook_label: …
send_to_voicemail: 0
is_autorecording: 0
data_id: 931
lookup: 654i6dbdb5460ae0585c
display_name: _Teste
last_time_contacted: 0
has_phone_number: 1
in_visible_group: 1
photo_file_id: null
label: null
starred: 0
normalized_number: null
photo_thumb_uri: null
in_default_directory: 1
photo_id: null
custom_ringtone: null
_id: 136
type: 3
times_contacted: 0
```

**EDIT:** Found a kind of janky workaround, by querying the full ContactsContract.Data table and put a bunch of Replaces in the selectionClause to ignore those separating characters:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '-', ''), '(', ''),')',''), ' ', '')
```

Comment: tried `Phone#CONTENT_FILTER_URI` ?

Comment: Yup it doesn't find it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful to someone: I've solved this problem by adding `%` after each character in the search query, so for `'123'` input we have `'%1%2%3%'` query. My lookup logic example:

```
// entered query from EditText    
private String cursorFilter;

...

public Loader<Cursor> contactsLoader() {
    Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA3};

    String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";

    String[] selectionArgs = {};
    String sortOrder = null;

    if (cursorFilter != null && !cursorFilter.isEmpty()) {
        // check is input digit or not
        char c = cursorFilter.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            // search through Phone.NUMBER
            String queryFilter = " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?";

            selectionArgs = new String[]{buildDigitFilter()};
            selection += queryFilter;
        } 
    }

    return new CursorLoader(
            сontext,
            contactsUri,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
}

private String buildDigitFilter() {
    StringBuilder filterBuilder = new StringBuilder("%");

    for (int i = 0; i < cursorFilter.length(); i++) {
        filterBuilder.append(cursorFilter.charAt(i))
                .append("%");
    }

    return filterBuilder.toString();
}
```